# Azure Kubernets deployment fail ....Error: Received bad response from Model Management Service: Response Code: 400

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-functions

Azure kubernets deployment fail....

WebserviceException:

```
Message: Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Failed
```

Operation ID: `cf9db31f-0466-41dd-b70f-fe5a9`

More information can be found using '.get_logs()'

```
Error:
{
  "code": "KubernetesDeploymentFailed",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "Kubernetes Deployment failed",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "CrashLoopBackOff",
      "message": "Your container application crashed. This may be caused by errors in your scoring file's init() function.\nPlease check the logs for your container instance: aks-service-fa2. From the AML SDK, you can run print(service.get_logs()) if you have service object to fetch the logs. \nYou can also try to run image c377cabf339b45c71.azurecr.io/azureml/azureml_bd83accc12:latest locally. Please refer to https://aka.ms/debugimage#service-launch-fails for more information."
    },
    {
      "code": "DeploymentFailed",
      "message": "Your container endpoint is not available. Please follow the steps to debug:\n1. From the AML SDK, you can run print(service.get_logs()) if you have service object to fetch the logs.
```

Comment: Did you try to run container from this image locally ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly suggests,

> Your container application crashed. This may be caused by errors in your scoring file's init() function.\nPlease check the logs for your container instance: aks-service-fa2. From the AML SDK, you can run print(service.get_logs()) if you have service object to fetch the logs. \nYou can also try to run image c377cabf339b45c71.azurecr.io/azureml/azureml_bd83accc12:latest locally. Please refer to https://aka.ms/debugimage#service-launch-fails for more information.

You need to check at the application log ([Inspect the Docker log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment-local#dockerlog)) what is the error and fix it.

```
# if you already have the service object handy
print(service.get_logs())

# if you only know the name of the service (note there might be multiple services with the same name but different version number)
print(ws.webservices['mysvc'].get_logs())
```